# Header still showing after set to null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I use react-navigation for my app, I have set it to null for the splash component, but it still shows when the splash component is showing please what may  I be doing wrong. `Search for your herbs...` isn't meant to show.
I was thinking of putting a state as the `header: this.state.header` so the state will be reset after the splash component has finished executing, i.e `this.setState({header: true})`, is this possible

[image: Search for your Herbs isn't meant to show]

**Splash.js**

```
export default class Splash extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require("../logo.png")} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Box extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Search for your herbs..."
        underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
        style={BackStyles.textBox}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**Home.js**

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: <Box />
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      record: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ timePassed: true });
    }, 4000);
    if (!this.state.timePassed) {
      return <Splash />;
    } else {
      const herbs = this.state.record.map(herb => (
        <View key={herb.id} style={BackStyles.herb_box}>
          <Image
            style={BackStyles.image}
            source={{ uri: `${herb.name.replace(/ /g, "")}` }}
          />
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
            <Text style={BackStyles.header}>{herb.name}</Text>
            <Text style={BackStyles.sub}>{herb.bot}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      ));
      return (
        <View style={BackStyles.main}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView overScrollMode={"never"}>{herbs}</ScrollView>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Home
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
      },
      headerTintColor: "#28B564",
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: "bold"
      }
    }
  }
);
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try headerMode: "none" right below initialRouteName: "Home",

Comment: The header will not show for the home component if i do that, I just want to hide the header for the splash component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered a problem similar to yours before, I think you should implement the splash component inside the App.js, i.e perform the setting of state of the timepassed variable in `APP.js`. So after the timepassed is true, you then show `<RootStack/>`

```
import Home from './components/Home';
import Splash from './components/Splash';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
    Home: Home
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#28B564',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
    },
}
);
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        timePassed: false,
    };
}

render() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({timePassed: true})
            }, 4000);
            if (!this.state.timePassed) {
            return <Splash/>;
            } else {
                return (
            <RootStack/>
             );

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Splash` component do this

```
static navigationOptions = {
  header: {
    visible: false,
  }
}
```

And in your `App.js` write this after `initialRouteName: "Home"` or inside `navigationOptions` (try both cases please)

```
headerMode: 'screen'
```

Comment: Did you add headerMode: 'screen' inside navigationOptions in App.js file? Please share your updated code.

Comment: I think it might be due to async loading of Splash component. One way to solving this issue is to set headerMode: 'none' in App.js file to disable all header. And then showing header in Home.js file using static navigationOptions.